# How to get Unique Column from database in c#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I am trying to get all unique column that is in a SQL Server table using c#.

For ex. I have table named "Emp" with the following columns:

```
Id (PK), Name, Address, SSN (Unique)
```

How can I retrieve columns that are only unique in C#?

Comment: How are you issuing queries to the database?  Are you just using the `SqlCommand` object in C# or are you using an ORM like Entity Framework?

Comment: I am using SqlCommand

Comment: Ok, one more question then.  What exactly do you want?  SSN you already have a unique constraint & PK is always unique, so do you mean you just want to get unique names or addresses?

Comment: Are you trying to figure out *which columns* contain unique data? Or which columns have uniqueness constraints? Or are you trying to get a `DISTINCT` set of the rows? Can you provide sample input and output?

Comment: Also, do you know how to do this in SQL normally?  If so, you should just look at the `SqlCommand` documentation to see how to issue the command.

Comment: I got all the column in my program but when i do columnName.unique check it only returns Id(which is PK) true but my SSN is also unique it doesn't return SSN as unique in my program.

Comment: @Matthew I am trying to get uniqueness constraints

Comment: Does your SSN column have a uniqueness constraint in SQL? Or is it *coincidentally* unique?

Comment: I used this script Alter Table Emp 
ADD CONSTRAINT AK_SSN UNIQUE (SSN) and I see the constraints on Indexes folder.

Answer (score 1):

Like this.

```
WITH i_unique AS (
    SELECT i.object_id, i.index_id
    FROM sys.indexes AS i
        INNER JOIN sys.index_columns AS ic
            ON ic.object_id = i.object_id
                AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
    WHERE i.is_unique = 1/*true*/
    GROUP BY i.object_id, i.index_id
    HAVING COUNT(ic.column_id) = 1
)
SELECT
    c.name AS 'column_name',
    i.name AS 'index_name'
FROM sys.objects AS o   
    INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS i
        INNER JOIN i_unique
            ON i_unique.object_id = i.object_id
                AND i_unique.index_id = i.index_id
        INNER JOIN sys.index_columns AS ic
            INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c
                ON c.object_id = ic.object_id
                    AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
            ON ic.object_id = i.object_id
                AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
        ON i.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE o.object_id = OBJECT_ID('Emp');
```

**Update:**

Keep in mind this returns a column when its the only column that its unique index contains. So, those on composite indexes are left out (since they're not unique on their own).